# How to collapse/group expo notifications

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo, getstream-io

#### Hello everybody

I'm currently developing an application that uses expo for push notifications. This app includes a chat feature that notifies the user of each message. The real problem is that these notifications are not collapsing immediately so the user gets a lot of notifications before android automatically decides to collapse.

#### Here's what is happening.

```
[App] John Doe
 Hello dude.
[App] John Doe
 How are you?
[App] John Doe
 Pay me!!!
```

The expected behaviour

```
[App] John Doe
  Hello dude
  How are you?
  Pay me!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like IOS automatically group all your App notifications into one thread. However, on Android you need to set `notification.androidMode` to `collapse`, which is not set by default.

Take a look at current documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#androidmode

```
app.json

Path: notification.androidMode
Type: enum

Show each push notification individually (default) or collapse into one (collapse).
```

That will only work in standalone app, nor in Expo Go.

Answer (score -2):

This requires support from backend for `collapse_key` in firebase which could be `channel_cid` for example, such that all messages on a channel ends up as one group.

I would suggest contacting support to ask for help from backend.